# Using multiple custom cells without reusing identifier

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I feel like a real noob asking this, but here's my problem:

I want to show a tableView, with 7 custom cells. None of these cells is reused. That means the user will see 7 different cells, not more, not less.

I created the cells in the viewDidLoad method, and added all those cells in the `listCells`-array. After that, I used easy-mode to draw those cells:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
if (indexPath.row == 0)
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"Cell";
    cell =  (DetAlertCell *)[localTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];

    if (cell == nil) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DetAlertCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [listCells objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
....
```

However, this won't work. It shows me a blank view.  Every cell is created using a .xib-file and a .h and .m class. Is there anything that I'm missing and should do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't call the `[localTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil]` and loa the correct cell for the index path.

Also you say that you load the cells in the viewDidLoad, then why do you load the nib:

```
 [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DetAlertCell" owner:self options:nil];
```

They should already be the array should they not.
And why to you check if the row is 0 then load the row, still will only load the first row.

Try this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   return [listCells objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

Comment: Seems to be working, I was totally confused on the bundle stuff... Hence my 'noob'-comment! Thanks!